# DB2 - Fetch tables which has a record inserted/updated/deleted from a particular time-stamp

Tags: sql, db2

IS there an sql query in DB2 that will fetch table/records where any record has been updated since a given time stamp ?

The following query I used only fetched if it is table change and not if records are updated.

```
SELECT TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || TRIM(TABNAME),
       MAX(CREATE_TIME,ALTER_TIME)
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Which platform of Db2? (Z/os, i-series, Unix/Windows).   If the table concerned has a row change timestamp or a timestamp column that is auto-maintained then you can use that column in a query.  Depending on the platform of Db2 and the version and what toolset is available and configured, you can also use auditing features, or transaction-log analysis to find this information.

Comment: @mao i need to find the table where any  column in a record is updated /inserted . It is not specific table but across whole DB

Comment: Then edit the question to show your platform/version and toolset available, as that will determine the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution would be to add a timestamp tracking column to each table, defaulting to `current timestamp` then select all `MAX()` values with a union and filter with a timestamp parameter.

The other solution is to create a `trigger` that updates a tracking table with the table name and current timestamp.